# Gears on the same axle question

Tags: gears

Do gears on the same axle share both speed and torque? So if a large gear and a small gear were in the same axle the small gear would have the torque of the large gear?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, of course. Or more accurately, one gear would have the *opposite* torque of the other. Torques, like forces, need to balance.

Comment: Interesting -  I interpreted the OP's question as "I'm driving an axle via some remote power source. If there are two gears on the axle, which one delivers more torque when meshed with an external gear?"